# Manga where mc has s-level restoration power and a guild leader recruits him to clear 7 wonders dungeon

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character has S-level restoration power and gets recruited by a guild whose leader has shadow type powers, also S-level, to defeat the 7 wonder dungeons on the condition that he (the guild leader) will help him (the restorer) to kill his friends who have lost their sanity after getting restored again and again in a dungeon break to keep them from dying. The restorer has to restore the dungeon since it is the 7 wonders of the world so that the other guild members can defeat the dungeon.  The use of their power causes them some kind of penalty such as there is a girl in the guild who has the ability to use gems to convert it to raw strength and the penalty is that whatever she touches turns to stone in the penalty time. There is also a magic user in the guild who is a fan of the restorer. The guild leader also has an older brother who is in politics and hates the guild leader.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember the names of any of the characters or the places they visit?  Was it in colour or black-and-white?

Comment: Are the people you talk about with penalties on their powers his former friends? Current members of the guild? Are the dungeons referred to as "wonder dungeons" or "the seven wonders of the world" or are you using that more metaphorically?

Comment: It was a coloured manga i read a year ago. And the penalties  are about the current member of the guild . I don't remember the name of the characters sorry . And the dungeon are actually 7 dungeons each based on the 7 wonders of the world

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be "A Trace of the Wonder", a webtoon (and previous webnovel) by Do Hae-neul, released in English as *[Traces of the Sun](https://manta.net/en/series/traces-of-the-sun?seriesId=1788)* on Manta. It opens with S-tier Hunter Sa Hyun, a member of the HN guild, with S-class shadow powers, approaching Jeong Yi-Seon, who has S-class restoration powers, to purify the Dungeons that have opened up around the world.

> I can help you kill your friends.
> Strange dungeons have started appearing all over the world and wreaking havoc. Yiseon, a guy with the power to rebuild cities, witnesses his friends being turned into the undead. Hyeon, a powerful hunter, comes to him with an interesting proposition. Yiseon has no choice but to accept his offer.

Doing a quick search, it seems that Aridas is the one who accidentally turns things to stone.

It's labeled as a Boy's Love comic if that is relevant.

Found with a search for `manga dungeons  "s class" restoration`